# How to call a function on completion of an asynchronus request - Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, sendasynchronousrequest

I have an asynchronus request in a class like this,

```
class Req{
    func processRequest(){
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
             //Do some operation here
        })
    }
}
```

And I am calling this method from one view controller like this,

```
class classOne{
    func classOneFun(){
        Req().processRequest()
        self.demoFun()
    }

    func demoFun(){
        //Do some operation here
    }
}
```

And I am calling the same function from another view controller like this,

```
class classTwo{

    func classTwoFun(){
        Req().processRequest()
        self.sampleFun()
    }

    func sampleFun(){
        //Do some operation here
    }
}
```

Now I want to call the `demoFun()` or `sampleFun()` only after the `processRequest()` is completed. If `demoFun() or sampleFun()` and `processRequest()` are in the same class, then I can call the functions in the completion handler of processRequest(). But, in my case I cannot do that, since I have nearly 20 view controllers that call the processRequest() function. I cannot use SynchronusRequest as it is deprecated in Swift 2.0. So how can I call the other functions once the asynchronus request is completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to modify your processRequest function to receive a closure. For example:

```
class Req{

        func processRequest(callback: Void ->Void){
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                 //Do some operation here
                 //Call the callback here:
                 callback()
            })
        }
    }
```

Now wherever, you want to call the processRequest API,  you can add the code you want to execute soon after your asynchronous callback processing. For example:

```
class classOne{
    func classOneFun(){
        Req().processRequest(){   //Passing the closure as a trailing closure with the code that we want to execute after asynchronous processing in processRequest
         self.demoFun()

}
    }

    func demoFun(){
        //Do some operation here
    }
}
```

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have not used `callback` and I do not know what it is. May I know how it works?

Comment: Or if you have any tutorials on this, can you share that here?

Comment: callback is the name of a parameter. Replace callBack with "closureThatIsGoingToBeCalledWhenTheRequestSucceeds" and see if it makes more sense.

Comment: What exactly did you not find in Apple's two Swift books? They explain everything at length.

Comment: Sure.. Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

Create blocks

```
class Req{
    func processRequest(success: () -> ()){
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            //Do some operation here
            success()
        })
    }
}


class classOne{
    func classOneFun(){
        Req().processRequest { () -> () in
            self.demoFun()
        }
    }

    func demoFun(){
        //Do some operation here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I can get some tutorials on the closures or callback functions, then it would be helpful to me..

Comment: you can look at the official document here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Comment: read this http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com if you dont have enough time :--\